# Render collection of models fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have AR relation of Post objects. Each post has `body` field. I need to render collection of this fields through array of posts.

**old version (bad perfomance way)**

```
- user.posts.each do |post|
  - if post.body.present?
    = render partial: "application/body", locals: {body: post.body}
```

**I need something like this:**

```
= render partial: "application/body", collection: user.posts, as: :body (but body is posts->post.body)
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `body` is a post's field, you can select posts bodies and pass as collection. There is useful `pluck` method, it selects only specified fields - it is more performant than `posts.map(&:body)`

```
= render partial: "application/body", collection: user.posts.pluck(:body), as: :body
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a tip. When iterating active record collection, it's better to use `find_each` instead of each: https://medium.com/@jonathanabrams/doing-stuff-with-rails-find-each-3f592ae02136

Rewriting it into `render .. collection` is also a nice option.

If you need to put all code into one line, you can write this:
`= render partial: 'application/body', collection: user.posts.where.not(body: [nil, false]), as: :post`

Or this:
`= render partial: 'application/body', collection: user.posts.where.not(body: [nil, false]).map(&:body), as: :body`

Also it would be good to put where condition into scope in `Post.rb`:
`scope :with_title, -> { where.not(posts: { body: [nil, false] })  }`

So final version of code would be this:
`= render partial: 'application/body', collection: user.posts.with_title.map(&:body), as: :body`

For further reading:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activerecord-s-where-not-and-nil
https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/ruby-map-method/